Disable SSIS tool tips
Is there any way to disable this tooltips within SSIS?
Its from VS22019,
The tooltip appears unnecessarily and never disappears even if the screens are switched, so at times its really annoying.

Additional screenshot

I couldn't find any options within VS2019 to disable this.

I had this bug with VS2015, VS2019 and still with VS2022. The solution proposed below by @billinkc works but it keeps coming back.

Seems to be a bug with the designer knowing when the mouseover event ends. I have to find the original package that is showing those items and then mouse over the content until it goes away.

Happy for a more authoritative answer to appear crosses fingers

Honestly, this has been a bug for as long as I can remember. It's annoying, but it doesn't stop productivity. Maybe Microsoft will fix it one day; I suspect it'll be when someone at Microsoft in the right position gets fed up of it happening to them.
